# Matching CSV file data to Text file data

Tags: python, csv, text, matching, string-matching

I am trying to create a tool which reads data from a txt file and csv file and finds where the ids in the text file match with the ids in the csv file. It will then write the results to a csv file. The orginal csv file will have column names, though the assumption is that the columns positioning can vary from file to file. So the match function will not be hard coded based off column positioning. Here is very low level code I have written which isn't quite working. Hoping someone can push me in the right direction.

```py
import csv

with open("test_file1.txt", "r") as file1:

    with open("test_file2.csv", "r") as file2:
        with open("results_file.csv", "w", newline= "") as csv_file:

            csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter= ",", quotechar= '"', quoting= csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            for line1 in file1:
                for line2 in file2:
                    if line1==line2:
                        csv_writer.writerow(line1, line2)
```

The csv file is created but there is nothing in the file. Not sure why.

Comment: Thanks for providing your code, and a clear explanation of the question.  Can you also provide a (small) sample input files and expected output file?  That will help folks looking at the question understand where things may be going wrong.

Comment: This line of code "if line1==line2:" - are the lines in the text file also comma delimited?  It looks like this line is saying that you only write an output line when the two lines are completely identical.  Did you mean to split the lines and check a particular field?

Answer (score 0):

Running the above code results in a `TypeError` being raised. The `csv_writer` supports only a single argument ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow))

You can instead write:

```py
csv_writer.writerow((line1, line2))
```

But the main problem, is that your `for` loop completes the iteration of `file2` in the first loop of the first line in `file1`, assuming the logic you have wrote is what you want, you most likely will need to do:

```py
with open("results_file.csv", "w", newline="") as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

with open("test_file1.txt", "r") as file1:
    for line1 in file1:
        with open("test_file2.csv", "r") as file2:
            for line2 in file2:
                _line1 = line1.replace("\n", "")
                _line2 = line2.replace("\n", "")
                csv_writer.writerow((_line1, _line2))
```